# How to convert string output of a function into an input or a runnable shell command?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, return-value

For example I use this code to get a value for mask

```
def get_rule(path, column_names):
    mask = ''
    for index, node in enumerate(path):
        #We check if we are not in the leaf
        if index!=len(path)-1:
            # Do we go under or over the threshold ?
            if (children_left[node] == path[index+1]):
                mask += "(df['{}']<= {}) \t ".format(column_names[feature[node]], threshold[node])
            else:
                mask += "(df['{}']> {}) \t ".format(column_names[feature[node]], threshold[node])
    # We insert the & at the right places
    mask = mask.replace("\t", "&", mask.count("\t") - 1)
    mask = mask.replace("\t", "")
    return mask
```

Once we run the function we get something like this:

```
>>> output = get_rule(...)
>>> output

"(df['A']<= 0.12) & (df['B']> 0.07) & (df['C']<= 0.24) & (df['D']<= 4.0) & (df['A']> 0.92)"
```

The output is in the form of a string and can therefore not be used as an input value.
For example:

```
>>> df[output]
```

will give the error:

```
KeyError: "(df['A']<= 0.12) & (df['B']> 0.07) & (df['C']<= 0.24) & (df['D']<= 4.0) & (df['A']> 0.92)"
```

My end goal is to use the output from the `get_rule` function directly into `df[ ]` to be able to find the region in the df, which I can else find by simply typing in this:

```
df[(df['A']<= 0.12) & (df['B']> 0.07) & (df['C']<= 0.24) & (df['D']<= 4.0) & (df['A']> 0.92)]
```

Comment: do you need the result in string format? it would be probably be easy to just compute the result as you go instead of using eval or exec on the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [**eval()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or [**exec()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) functions. These functions let you run dynamic python code in the form of `str`.

For example:

```
exec("x = 1234")  # executes x = 1234 (set value of x to 1234)
eval("2 + 3 * 5")  # returns 17
```

So you might want to use it like this:

```
eval(f"df[{output}]")  # Can't use exec() here because it doesn't return value
```